# Separating click event from .h (designer code) to .cpp file

Tags: header, c++-cli, organization

I've run into an organization problem with windows application form that I need some help with.  Right now the code is done in microsoft studio 2010 in .net 4.0 in c++.  The header file for the GUI application is not organized which can potentially lead to 10,000 or more lines of code, which makes it very difficult to read.

I was trying to separate the click event implementation into a .cpp file that included the "Form1.h".

```c
private:
    System::Void sIToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
        switch(this->USCustomaryFlg){
        case true:
            this->sIToolStripMenuItem->Checked = true;
            this->mnuUSMetric->Checked = false;
            this->USCustomaryFlg = false;
            cout << "SI flag is now true." << endl;
            break;
        case false:
            break;
        }
    }
```

into this form in the .cpp file of Form1:

```c
System::Void mnuUSMetric_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
    switch(this->USCustomaryFlg){
    case true:
        cout << "USCustomaryFlg is now false." << endl;
        break;
    case false:
        this->mnuUSMetric->Checked = true;
        this->USCustomaryFlg = true;
        this->sIToolStripMenuItem->Checked = false;
        cout << "USCustomaryFlg is now true." << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The error I've been receiving are just a sample of what I've been getting:

> Error  2   error C2355: `'this'` : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions   E:\Summer 2011\Engineer Software\GUItest\GUItest\Form1.cpp  16
>
> Error  4   error C2355: `'this'` : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions   E:\Summer 2011\Engineer Software\GUItest\GUItest\Form1.cpp  21
>
> Error  3   error C2227: left of `'->USCustomaryFlg'` must point to class/struct/union/generic type E:\Summer 2011\Engineer Software\GUItest\GUItest\Form1.cpp  16
>
> Error  8   error C2227: left of `'->USCustomaryFlg'` must point to class/struct/union/generic type E:\Summer 2011\Engineer Software\GUItest\GUItest\Form1.cpp  22

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is not C++. I have retagged it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your C++ method is **defined** (i.e. has its body written) separately from its **declaration** (i.e. it's signature inside of class), you need to prefix method definition with class name.

E.g. if your class is named `MyForm` the definition should be

```
System::Void MyForm::mnuUSMetric_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, and leave the declaration of the method in the .h file.

Comment: It's never defined separately from its *definition*, because its *definition* is, by definition, where it was defined.  I think you meant *declaration*.